# Cyclic lists of multisets

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

I am wondering if it is appropriate to ask about having a specific algebra for an endofunctor computed.  We all know about the [multiset monad](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2459797/), and it's endofunctor $\mathcal{M}_S$, and some might know about the [cyclic lists endofunctor](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231537572_Data_Types_with_Symmetries_and_Polynomial_Functors_over_Groupoids), $\mathcal{L}_C$.  I need to know all about the composition of these, so $\mathcal{L}_C \otimes \mathcal{M}_S$, so cyclic lists of multisets.  I would like to know about the algebra for this endofunctor composition.

I would like to know if the monads compose as I have written them.  If so, what is the Eilenberg-Moore category of the composite monad?

For a base category, sets is fine.

Comment: You also want a [distributive law](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributive+law) to know that the monads compose to give a monad. And, if you are over the 2-category Gpd, do you want a strict monad or a pseudomonad?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thanks for the good input.  I am afraid the questions of strict vs pseudo will take some time for me to have a guess at.

Comment: Maybe edit the question so that it doesn't refer to monads that don't exist?

Comment: @DavidRoberts lol yah

Comment: I don't have any particular insights, but is the cyclic list endofunctor pointed? Then one can still try a weak form of distributive law (i.e. just the triangular diagrams at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributive+law#explicit_definition) to see if the composite you seek is a _pointed_ endofunctor (pointed algebras over pointed endofunctors are defined at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebra+for+an+endofunctor)

Comment: I want to maybe push a little to get details on the cyclic lists endofunctor. At the reference, this is all that is given: the data required to specify a polynomial endofunctor of $\mathbf{Gpd}$, namely the "forget the point functor" from the groupoid of cyclicly-orderd finite sets with chosen point to the groupoid of cyclicly-ordered sets. A recipe is given for getting an endofunctor of $\mathbf{Set}$, namely $\mathbf{Set}\hookrightarrow \mathbf{Gpd}\to \mathbf{Gpd} \stackrel{\pi_0}{\to} \mathbf{Set}$. Is this what is intended in the original question?

Comment: In particular, what would be nice is a version of the multiset monad that is in fact an endofunctor of $\mathbf{Gpd}$, so that these thing can be sensibly composed "natively", rather than passing to the endofunctor of $\mathbf{Set}$ for the cyclic list endofunctor. A type mismatch like this smells to me that something could a bit amiss with this idea, in its current form. Further, why do you suspect this order of composition is the right one? Why not the other way?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thank you for considering this question.  I don't really understand, or like, the idea of the specified point.  Kock talks about pointed cyclic sets and I don't get that either.  I was speaking to Hofstra and he suggested that cyclic lists are a monad on Rel.  Rel has been used as a pseudo classical stand-in for FdHilb.  The reason I mention this is just that the whole question is motivated by a desire for an alternate derivation of a quantum-like category of algebras.  I guess what I am saying is that, since the base category is a choice, something like Rel can be considered.

Comment: The pointed cyclic lists are just part of the machinery that defines the polynomial endofunctor. I think even the free monad endofunctor can be built in a similar way, using the forgetful map from pointed finite sets. They do not appear in the final product. The point (hah) is that what you need a map whose fibres have a certain structure, and the point-forgetting map has this structure. I'll come back to this question a bit later.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I am using my guiding intuition from physics to think about the reverse of the composite functor.  This would be a bag of cyclic lists.  This might work.  This would be the corpus of all polarization experiments where the wave plate was rotated by some fraction of a whole rotation.  It makes a bit of sense to me.  I postulate that the product axiom of monads actually models the scientific effect that large collections of experiments can be put together into a single body "about a subject".  I think, you, the point of cyclic list of multisets is to give a Symmetry to Multisets.

Comment: You are using your intuition to think about a functor that you haven't given us the definition of, merely pointed to a definition that is implicit and defined on a different category. It's not clear to me if what you are thinking of is the same as the thing in Kock's paper. Can you write out a complete explicit description of the cyclic list endofunctor on $\mathbf{Set}$ (or $\mathbf{FinSet}$, or $\mathbf{FinSet}_{\mathrm{bijections}}$? All of this is prerequiste to even trying to write down an algebra for a composite endofunctor.

Comment: It's all very well and good having intuitive physics ideas, but a functor is more than the vague idea of "I have a bag of cyclic lists". What are the morphisms? What is the effect of functoriality?